# Removing +\ when saving in Php

Tags: php

I am saving this string

```
  $string= ~`!@#$%^&*()_-=+\][‘;/.,<>?:”{}|
```

as `htmlentities(urlencode(addslashes(trim($string))));`

But it is  removing `+\` and returning me string as `~!@#$%^&*()_-= ][‘;/.,<>?:”{}|`.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I don't find any +\ on your first string.

Comment: Neither of those characters exist in the original string. Why are you using `addslashes` in combination with `urlencode` and `htmlentities`?

Comment: @Md.SahadatHossain I placed +\ but stackoverflow removed it.So i edited it again

Comment: I belive htmlentities should be used when you have any html tags in your string. But this does not seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

You should use enclose your string between `" "`, since it is not a variable. Also, `\` is used as an escape command. To view `\`, you should type `\\`, that will escape the escape command. You are entering `"` on your string too, so I guess you would like to escape it.

```
$string= "~`!@#$%^&*()_-=+\\][‘;/.,<>?:\”{}|";
```

Even StackOverflow did delete that `+\` thing. You shouldn't have any problem acting like this anyway.